# Query Multiple SObject using Salesforce Cli

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Is it possible to export multiple SObjects data records without using Parent Child relationship? Suppose there are 2 SObjects Transaction__c and Country__c independent of each other.. I want to export both records in single go.. Is it possible using salesforce cli?

Following is the command I am using to export data using Salesforce CLI:

Command to fetch Transaction__c

> sfdx force:data:tree:export -q "Select Name from Transaction__c" -u MyScratchOrg

Command to fetch Country__c

> sfdx force:data:tree:export -q "Select Name from Country__c" -u MyScratchOrg

I want to combine above 2 commands in single command without Parent-Child relationship Query.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `sfdx force:data:tree:export` accepts exactly one SOQL query per invocation. It won't accept `-q` twice, and you won't be able to specify both objects if they do not have a relationship to one another.

For now, you'll be stuck with running the command twice, unless and until SFDX gets more sophisticated export behavior.